# Ability to have a search feature to find search through personal question history

Tags: feature-request, search, profile-page, questions

Sometimes, I want to find a question I asked but I find it difficult it to scroll through all my asked questions trying to find one question. So, I suggest that this site includes a search feature in the "asked questions" page of profile for ease of life purposes.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the advanced search functionality: searching for e.g. [`user:me is:q derivative`](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+derivative) will give all posts by you, which are questions, and contain the word 'derivative':

[image]